# Submersion theorem clarification

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to digest the following theorem and a question came up. Let $U$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and $F: U\to \Bbb R^m$ be a smooth function where $m$ is smaller than $n$. If the set of all $p$ in $U$ where $F(p)=0$ has no critical points then this set is an $n-m$ dimensional manifold. My question is would this theorem also be valid if instead of $0$ be choose any other real number?

Comment: The question is incomplete, I recommend you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your post.

Answer (score 2):

First, the $0$ in $F(p)=0$ is not a real number, it is the origin of $\Bbb R^m$.

This being said, yes, you could choose any other element of $\Bbb R^m$ instead, since you can always translate the function: $$G(x)=F(x)-a$$ will have the same critical points as $F$, except $G^{-1}(0)$ is $F^{-1}(a)$. Applying the original theorem to $G$ tells you that $F^{-1}(a)$ is a submanifold if it doesn't contain critical points.